# SQL Server 2005: SELECT default value of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a script that analyses database tables and I'm having problems with fetching the default value of columns from SQL Server 2005.

The following works fine on SQL Server 2008, but when I run the same thing on SQL Server 2005, the result is an empty string, and I can't figure out why.

```
DECLARE @sDatabase VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @sTable VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @sColumn VARCHAR(100);

SET @sDatabase = 'SomeDatabase';
SET @sTable = 'tbl_something';
SET @sColumn = 'SomethingID';

SELECT
    syscolumns.name AS column_name,
    systypes.name column_type,
    syscolumns.length AS column_length,
    syscolumns.prec AS column_precision,
    syscolumns.scale AS column_scale,
    syscolumns.isnullable AS column_nullable,
    syscomments.text AS column_default_value -- Should be default value!
FROM
    sysobjects 
    INNER JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    INNER JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype = systypes.xtype
    LEFT OUTER JOIN syscomments ON syscomments.id = syscolumns.cdefault
WHERE sysobjects.xtype = 'U'
AND sysobjects.name = @sTable
AND systypes.name != 'sysname'
ORDER BY
    sysobjects.name,
    syscolumns.colid
```

Another version is as follows, but it's the same story; returns an empty string on SQL Server 2005, but the correct value on SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = @sDatabase
AND TABLE_NAME = @sTable
AND COLUMN_NAME = @sColumn
```

This is used for comparing certain changes between databases. Originally I thought that the problem was because SQL Server 2005 returned default values such as "((0))" while SQL Server 2008 was returning "(0)" for the same default value of the integer 0. That's what SQL Server Management Studio reports respectively. But upon further investigation, it turns out that the default values of SQL Server 2005 are simply not being displayed at all, so it is always recorded as a change when in fact there is none.

Any help deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the `sys.default_constraints` view?

This snippet finds the default for table `TestTable` column `nr`:

```
create table TestTable (nr float default 3.13)

select  definition
from    sys.default_constraints dc
join    sys.columns c
on      c.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
        and c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
where   parent_object_id = object_id('TestTable')
        and c.name = 'nr'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but with the same results. That means there's something strange going on because it didn't work on SQL Server 2008, but the command ran on SQL Server 2005... only with the results, i.e. none.